# "kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property madapter has not been initialized at..." when setting up RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview, kotlin-lateinit

Line throwing error:

```kotlin
recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
```

Code:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NewsItemClicked {
    private lateinit var recyclerView:RecyclerView
    private lateinit var mAdapter: NewsListAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        fetchData()

        val verticalLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
             recyclerView.layoutManager = verticalLayoutManager
        recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
    }

    private fun fetchData() {
        val url =
            "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=*****"
        val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            null,
            {
                val newsJsonArray = it.getJSONArray("articles")
                val newsArray = ArrayList<News>()
                for (i in 0 until newsJsonArray.length()) {
                    val newsJsonObject = newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    val news = News(
                        newsJsonObject.getString("title"),
                        newsJsonObject.getString("author"),
                        newsJsonObject.getString("url"),
                        newsJsonObject.getString("urlToImage")
                    )
                    newsArray.add(news)
                }
                mAdapter.updateNews(newsArray)
            }, {

            }

        )
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)
    }
    override fun onItemClicked(item: News) {
        val builder = CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
        val customTabsIntent = builder.build()
        customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(item.url))
    }
}
```

Error from logcat:

```
2021-01-19 18:38:40.819 3869-3869/com.example.newsfresh E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.newsfresh, PID: 3869
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newsfresh/com.example.newsfresh.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property madapter has not been initialized
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property madapter has not been initialized
        at com.example.newsfresh.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7088)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7079)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Comment: `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property madapter has not been initialized at `... you're using a lateinit variable which you haven't initialized. want more help ? have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sharing your code, and explaining what are you doing, will help us to help you.

Comment: @Sourcerer I have added

Comment: @Sourcerer I am making a news app with recyclerView and API call

Comment: You haven't assigned anything to ``mAdapter``

Comment: @cactustictacs what should I assign?

Comment: Create a ``NewsListAdapter`` and assign it before it's read by anything (e.g. ``recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter``). If it's any more complicated than that we won't be able to help you, we don't know how the app works - if you didn't write it then you might have to ask whoever did, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized your `lateinit var mAdapter` variable.

Kotlin allows you to access it despite it being uninitialized because it's `lateinit`, but it will throw this exception.  You could solve this one of two ways:

#### Remove `lateinit`, initialize at declaration site:

In this case, it could be a `val`:

```kotlin
private val mAdapter = NewsListAdapter(...)
```

This assumes that you have everything needed to set up the adapter when the `Activity` is started.  You'll likely need to call one of the `notify...` methods on it once data is available.

If you don't...

#### Make sure it's initialized before you use it

```
mAdapter = NewsListAdapter(...)
recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
```

Answer (score 0):

Or check before:

```
if (this::recyclerView.isInitialized) {
    ...
}
```